# Symfony 2, choices from database

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to display a form with a "select" where is the "options" from a query.

```
 $results = $conn->query(" select gsm, name from Contact");
 $row = $results->fetchAll();
```

and after that: I trying to use this

```
 foreach($row as $lign)
    $centretechnique[$lign['gsm']] = $lign['name'];
```

and in formbuilder

```
$form->add('centretechnique', 'choice', array('required' => false, 'error_bubbling' => true, "empty_value" => "Choisir ", 'choices' => $centretechnique));
```

I want to display a list of select option with value=gsm and the displayed value is the `name`

this method llow me to display , but the problem that if I have duplicate option, only on option will be displayed.

for example, the result of the request is

```
  array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'gsm' => string '628436515' (length=9)
      'name' => string 'name1' (length=7)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'gsm' => string '628436515' (length=9)
      'name' => string 'name 2' (length=4)
```

just one option will be displayed.

any help please

Answer (score 1):

If you want to populate choices form type from the database, then you should be using the [form entity type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html).

Something like this:

```
$form->add(
    'centretechnique',
    'entity',
    array(
        'class' => 'MyBundle:Contact',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
        },
        'choice_label' => 'name',
        'choice_value' => 'gsm',
        'multiple'      => false,
        'expanded'      => false,
        'required'      => false,
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

By building your choices you do :

```
 $centretechnique[$lign['gsm']] = $lign['name'];
```

So **your code** does overwrite the first choice with the second, since you use the same key twice ...